# [joint_state_publisher]: Waiting for robot_description to be published on the robot_description topic

Tags: ros2, urdf, roslaunch

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Im using the below python launch file:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import os
import sys

from ament_index_python.packages import get_package_share_directory


import rclpy
from rclpy.node import Node

from std_msgs.msg import String
import launch
import launch_ros.actions
from launch import LaunchDescription
from launch_ros.actions import Node
from launch_ros.substitutions import FindPackageShare

def generate_launch_description():
    # Load the URDF into a parameter
    bringup_dir = get_package_share_directory('urdfpublisher')
    urdf_path = os.path.join(bringup_dir, 'urdf', 'doggo.urdf')
    urdf = open(urdf_path).read()

    return launch.LaunchDescription([
        launch_ros.actions.Node(
            name='robot_state_publisher',
            package='robot_state_publisher',
            executable='robot_state_publisher',
            parameters=[{'robot_description': urdf}],
        ),
        launch_ros.actions.Node(
            name='joint_state_publisher',
            package='joint_state_publisher',
            executable='joint_state_publisher',
            parameters=[{'use_gui': True}],
        )
    ])



def main(argv=sys.argv[1:]):
    """Run lifecycle nodes via launch."""
    ld = generate_launch_description()
    ls = launch.LaunchService(argv=argv)
    ls.include_launch_description(ld)
    
    #launch robot_description topic
    node = rclpy.create_node('robot_description')
    publisher = node.create_publisher(generate_launch_description, 'robot_description', 10)
    
    #Fails when generating launch description with joint state publisher here
    publisher.publish(generate_launch_description)
    
    #publisher = node.create_publisher(String, 'sos')
    
    return ls.run()



if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

to try and publish robot_description and joint_state_publisher with GUI enabled but I get  the error "[joint_state_publisher]: Waiting for robot_description to be published on the robot_description topic..." thrown. When i remove joint_state_publisher, RVIZ2 is able to correctly pick up on robot_description meaning it should be getting published. The terminal logs also look nearly identical when joint_state_publisher is removed.

Launch file log with joint_state_publisher removed from "return launch.LaunchDescription" block:

```
[INFO] [launch]: Default logging verbosity is set to INFO
[INFO] [robot_state_publisher-1]: process started with pid [7135]
[robot_state_publisher-1] Parsing robot urdf xml string.
[robot_state_publisher-1] Link body_link had 0 children
[robot_state_publisher-1] [INFO] [1594658144.778155573] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment base_link
[robot_state_publisher-1] [INFO] [1594658144.778254258] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment body_link
```

Launch file log when joint_state_publisher isn't removed

```
[INFO] [launch]: Default logging verbosity is set to INFO
[INFO] [robot_state_publisher-1]: process started with pid [7078]
[INFO] [joint_state_publisher-2]: process started with pid [7080]
[robot_state_publisher-1] Parsing robot urdf xml string.
[robot_state_publisher-1] Link body_link had 0 children
[robot_state_publisher-1] [INFO] [1594657967.525358734] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment base_link
[robot_state_publisher-1] [INFO] [1594657967.525620189] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment body_link
[joint_state_publisher-2] [INFO] [1594657968.330320388] [joint_state_publisher]: Waiting for robot_description to be published on the robot_description topic...
```

Not sure why joint_state_publisher is being finicky and the joint_state_publisher GitHub page doesn't have any .py launch file examples.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/357042/%5Bjoint_state_publisher%5D:-waiting-for-robot_description-to-be-published-on-the-robot_description-topic.../) by [rydb](https://answers.ros.org/users/53251/rydb/) on ROS Answers with karma: 125 on 2020-07-13

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It seems I made a simple mistake, I couldnt find the joint state publisher for foxy for some reason but after following an example of how to use it [here](https://github.com/ros/joint_state_publisher/blob/foxy/joint_state_publisher/test/test_zero_joints.py) , it seems I wasn confusing ROS1 xml with ros2 python. I made a small revision to the joint_state_publisher node and it launches properly and the robot_state_publisher node listents to it without issue:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import os
import sys

from ament_index_python.packages import get_package_share_directory

import launch
import launch_ros.actions


def generate_launch_description():
    # Load the URDF into a parameter
    bringup_dir = get_package_share_directory('urdfpublisher')
    urdf_path = os.path.join(bringup_dir, 'urdf', 'doggo.urdf')
    urdf = open(urdf_path).read()

    return launch.LaunchDescription([
        launch_ros.actions.Node(
            name='robot_state_publisher',
            package='robot_state_publisher',
            executable='robot_state_publisher',
            parameters=[{'robot_description': urdf}],
        ),
        launch_ros.actions.Node(
            package='joint_state_publisher',
            executable='joint_state_publisher',
            arguments=(urdf_path),
        ),
    ])


def main(argv=sys.argv[1:]):
    rospy.init_node('joint_state_publisher_gui')
    """Run lifecycle nodes via launch."""
    ld = generate_launch_description()
    ls = launch.LaunchService(argv=argv)
    ls.include_launch_description(ld)
    return ls.run()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()

[INFO] [launch]: Default logging verbosity is set to INFO
[INFO] [robot_state_publisher-1]: process started with pid [30524]
[INFO] [joint_state_publisher-2]: process started with pid [30526]
[robot_state_publisher-1] Parsing robot urdf xml string.
[robot_state_publisher-1] Link body_link had 0 children
[robot_state_publisher-1] [INFO] [1595439722.097627686] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment base_link
[robot_state_publisher-1] [INFO] [1595439722.097767815] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment body_link
```

---

Originally posted by [rydb](https://answers.ros.org/users/53251/rydb/) with karma: 125 on 2020-07-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dgarcialopez](https://answers.ros.org/users/52017/dgarcialopez/) on 2021-07-24**:
I was having the same issue and you help me fix it! Just a quick note: to avoid an error, arguments must be provided in square brackets '[ ]' not in round ones '( )'. So the correct way to launch the node is:

```
launch_ros.actions.Node(
        package='joint_state_publisher',
        executable='joint_state_publisher',
        arguments=[urdf_path],
    ),
```

To use gui window you should launch 'joint_state_publisher_gui' node instead:

```
launch_ros.actions.Node(
        package='joint_state_publisher_gui',
        executable='joint_state_publisher_gui',
        arguments=[urdf_path],
    ),
```

Don't forget to have both packages installed (foxy in my case):

```
sudo apt install ros-foxy-joint-state-publisher
sudo apt install ros-foxy-joint-state-publisher-gui
```